# Query Edge Nodes & Edge Properties

Tags: python, python-2.7, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'd like to get a list of edge properties in the form of

```
[ {'src': nodeid, 'dst': nodeid, 'item': itemid},
  {'src': nodeid, 'dst': nodeid, 'item': itemid},
  ...
]
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334577/get-edge-properties-as-well-as-source-and-target-vertex-id-in-gremlin-query-lang), I formulate the query as the following in gremlin_python:

```
g.V(user_list).bothE().hasLabel('share_item').dedup(). \
                project('src','dst','item'). \
                    by(outV().id()). \
                    by(inV().id()) \
                    by(coalesce(values('item_id'),constant(''))). \
                .toList()
```

However, I got the following error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I am able to get a list of 'src' and 'dst' with

```
g.V(user_list).bothE().hasLabel('share_item').dedup(). \
                project('src','dst'). \
                    by(outV().id()). \
                    by(inV().id()) \
                .toList()
```

Did i miss out any python keyword? Or may I know what's the limitation lies in gremlin python?

---

Updates:

In my case, I do have a workaround for this. Only edges contain (src, dst, item) will be extracted however.

```
g.V(user_list).bothE().hasLabel('share_item').dedup(). \
                has('item'). \
                project('src','dst'). \
                    by(outV().id()). \
                    by(inV().id()) \
                    by('item'). \
                toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `values('item_id')` is somehow being confused with the `Column.values` enum. What you want there is the traversal step `values()` which is exposed from the `__` class. Having imported the `__` class, please try changing your code to:

```
g.V(user_list).bothE().hasLabel('share_item').dedup(). \
            project('src','dst','item'). \
                by(outV().id()). \
                by(inV().id()) \
                by(coalesce(__.values('item_id'),constant(''))). \
            .toList()
```

Comment: I got "TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)"  with this. BTW, I did import "from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __"  and "statics.load_statics(globals())"